# Reemplazar con re.sub() todos los grupor resultado de un patrón

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un documento con marcas xml. Debo localizar el texto contenido entre marcas específicas y en esos textos debo eliminar todas la posibles marcas que aparezcan, dejando así el documento original limpio.

Selecciono con re.findall() todos los grupos entre las marcas indicadas. Por ejemplo

```
import re

# Con la siguiente cadena
cadena = 'Texto<span class="str_">"El <i>famoso</i> hidalgo don <em>Quijote de la 
Mancha</em>"</span>más texto<span class="str_">"AAAA"</span>otro texto.\n<span class="str_">"<b>BBBB</b>"</span>'
# Buscando entre las marcas <span class="str_"></span>
# con el siguiente patrón
patron = r'<span class="str_">(.*?)</span>'
# El resultado del findall
resultado = re.findall(patron, cadena)
print(resultado)


['"El <i>famoso</i> hidalgo don <em>Quijote de la Mancha</em>"', '"AAAA"', '"<b>BBBB</b>"']
```

Elimino todas las marcas interiores de la forma:

```
# Con el siguiente patrón busco cualquier grupo de marcas
p_marcas = "((<\/\w+>|<\w+>))"
# Actuando sobre el primer grupo obtenido anteriormente
sin_marcas = re.sub(p_marcas, '', resultado[0])
# El resultado del sub deja limpio el texto
print(sin_marcas)


'"El famoso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha"'
```

La pregunta es ¿Como puedo unir las dos operaciones en una? ¿Como obtener todos los posibles grupos (cosa que hago) y modificarlos todo con una sola expresión?
Hasta ahora todos mis intentos han acabado con un bonito Traceback

**Encontrada la solución. La pongo a continuación por si es de ayuda.**

```
    # Función para realizar el reemplazamiento
    def reemplaza(m):
        return re.sub(p_marcas, '', m.group()) + '</span>'
    
    # Compilar patrón
    p = re.compile(patron)
    
    # Realizar la sustitución de los grupos
    cadena_sin_marcas = p.sub(reemplaza, cadena)
    
    print(cadena_sin_marcas)
    Texto<span class="str_">"El famoso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha"</span>más texto<span class="str_">"AAAA"</span>otro texto.
<span class="str_">"BBBB"</span>
```

Defino una función que será la encargada de hacer el reemplazamiento.
Una vez compilado el patrón de búsqueda, se llama con el patrón compilado a sub() que hace uso de la función para el reemplazamiento.
No es una cosa que se te ocurra de entrada, pero funciona.

Nota. El añadir la marca '`</span>`' al retorno es porque con el patrón que busca las marcas, *p_marcas*, me desaparece. Pero eso es otra historia.

Comment: Es obligatorio usar regex? Eso tiene pinta de html más que xml. Y tanto para html como xml existen parsers (el parser xml viene con Python) que son mucho mejores que regex. Por cierto, para fusionar ambas operaciones es necesario modificar la regex y pasarsela a re.sub. No se me ocurre otra forma.

Comment: Sí. El ejemplo ha quedado un poco simple, pero tampoco era cuestión de poner una parrafada enorme.

Comment: @Dante. Gracias, lo de pasar el patrón a sub() fue una primera idea que me llevó a la solución que he puesto más arriba. Tu idea + la búsqueda + cabezón que es uno, ahí queda una posible solución.